# Services bus message receive in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I created one ServicesBus queue and start sending thousands of messages

```
await queueClient.SendBatchAsync(brokeredMessagesList);
```

Another side I created azure function to receive messages form ServicesBus  queue. here is my code

```
public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("batch-input", AccessRights.Manage,
        Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
    {
        string body;
        using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        SampleMessage sampleMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleMessage>(body);

        await SaveMessageIntoAzureTableAsync(sampleMessage);
        //await message.CompleteAsync();
        log.Info($"Message body: {sampleMessage}");
    }
```

This code working in my local but I'm more curious about scaling and batch processing.

How azure function scaling will work with large no of message in queue?? I don't see any documentation

Prefetch Count setting will apply on local? [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#prefetching) I saw default prefetching count is 100.

When should I call complete method (with or without this my code is working)?

```
await message.CompleteAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions runtime will retrieve messages in batches and call multiple function invocations in parallel. You can adjust Prefetch Count and some other settings with [`host.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) file.

If queue size keeps growing, Azure will spin up more instances, which would also do processing in parallel.

You should never call `CompleteAsync` explicitly, this will be done for you by the runtime for any successful execution.

Comment: I'm partially getting your answer. If I have 1M messages in queue and PrefectCount=100. one instance of Azure function will start processing 100 messages in parallel. (per-message processing average is time .5 mins) how Auzre will spin up more instance? what is the calculation?

Comment: @PankajRawat The exact scale out algorithm / strategy is a black box managed by Azure, not documented anywhere.